# When DrRacket compiles symbols, are they interned in the executable's symbol table?

Tags: racket, symbols

The documentation for DrRacket says that all symbols are interned, but how can that be the case in a executable?  Are the symbols registered in the executable's symbol table or somewhere else?

Comment: To be clear, the data structure known as a symbol is different from a symbol (e.g., function name) in a compiled executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're interned in the internal heap of the application. So you could consider them "part" of the executable, but they're not part of a symbol table that something like a linker would know to look for, they're not exported in that way. They're in the internal symbol table of the application, which is part of the heap.